# Integrating botpress as backend to chat widget built in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, chatbot, botpress

I am using react chat widget as frontend and I want to connect it to botpress as the backend for functioning. I have a function in my app.js file. `handleNewUserMessage` is the function responsible to hit botpress and getback the response.

Here is the code in react:

```js
    handleNewUserMessage = (newMessage) => {    
    toggleMsgLoader();
    setTimeout(() => {
      toggleMsgLoader();      
      if (newMessage === 'fruits') {
        setQuickButtons([ { label: 'Apple', value: 'apple' }, { label: 'Orange', value: 'orange' }, { label: 'Pear', value: 'pear' }, { label: 'Banana', value: 'banana' } ]);
      } else {
        addResponseMessage(newMessage);
      }
    }, 2000);
```